# How to define data series in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a python newb having only learnt in last 3 month.
I have a .csv file with +1000columns of data.
Each row is related to a specific data series with each column a row.

I am struggling to define each data series within my code - and then column series as well - though I feel this will be easier?

This is my most complex code I have written so I am both very excited whilst doing it but running into problems with my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with loading your csv with `pandas` using

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: I have done this. Everything imported correctly - I am struggling with defining the series. My current code is:


<code>
y4 = series('4YR')
y5 = series('5YR')
y6= series('6YR')
y7= series('7YR')
y8= series('8YR')
y10 = series('10YR')
y15 = series('15YR')
y20= series('20YR')
y30= series('30YR')
</code>

Comment: By doing this you import your csv into a DataFrame object that already contains Series of your data. What exactly do you want to do with your data ?

Comment: Want to use the data to plot a graph for each date to create a GIF/Video. Similiar to below but using a line graph: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhqeWMvvnYM&ab_channel=TheRankings

Comment: then you should look into the pandas documentation for plots, here is a quick intro : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html Happy coding !